# How to check if an html element contains it's own text (contains textNode)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am going to check if an html element contains it's own text.

**Examples are**
`<div>Text<tag></tag>Text</div>` and `<div>Text</div>`.

**Some thing that not fit  is**
`<div><tag></tag><p></p></div>`

My code snippet is

```
flag = false;
for ( var j = 0; j < item.childNodes.length; j ++){
    if(item.childNodes[j].tagName == ""){
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

But it's not working, can someone help me with this?

**What I expected was**
`<div>Text<tag></tag>Text</div>`'s child nodes are `Text`, `<tag></tag>` and `Text`.
But it's not.

Comment: Do you want to check if it has textNodes as direct children ?

Comment: yes, quite right

Comment: @jaboja's answer is spot on, then.

Comment: I will try, thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to detect the text node child, check if *nodeType* is TEXT_NODE instead of if *tagName* is empty string:

```
var flag = Array.from(item.childNodes).some(child => child.nodeType === child.TEXT_NODE);
```